# Force to extend a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose a long solenoid has length $l$, area $S$ and $N$ turns.
I want to know the force required to extend it when the current is $I$.

Since $B=\mu_0\frac{N}{l}I$, the total energy is $$\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\cdot Sl = \frac{1}{2}\mu_0N^2I^2S\frac{1}{l} \propto \frac{1}{l}.$$ Therefore, electromagnetic force tries to extend the solenoid.

However, I think it cannot be true because currents of the same direction attract each other.  What did I overlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you work at constant intensity.

In this case, if you imagine an elementary deformation of the circuit the magnetic energy varies but at the same time the generator provides energy to maintain the current against the induced emf.

Finally, by a classical reasoning one writes $\text{d}{{E}_{m}}=-{{F}_{x}}\text{d}x+i\text{d}\Phi $ or even $\text{d}{{\tilde{E}}_{m}}=-{{F}_{x}}\text{d}x-\Phi di$ with the "coenergy" ${{\tilde{E}}_{m}}={{E}_{m}}-i\Phi =-{{E}_{m}}$.

What ultimately gives ${{F}_{x}}=-{{\left( \frac{\partial {{{\tilde{E}}}_{m}}}{\partial x} \right)}_{i}}=+{{\left( \frac{\partial {{E}_{m}}}{\partial x} \right)}_{i}}$

**The constant-current potential energy is the opposite of magnetic energy.**

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

A solenoid under current indeed experiences tension that acts to expand its radius ("so called magnetic pressure"). This is due to magnetic (Ampere) forces between axially opposed wire elements carrying electric current. Consider single coil and its opposing elements 1,2:

```
   _________
 /           \
|             |
|1     x      |2
|3            |
 \__________ /
```

The directions of electric current in those two elements are exactly opposed to each other. So the forces between the two are repulsive. There are also attractive forces between pairs such as 1,3, so the coils are attracted to each other, but these forces are mainly in the tangential direction so they do not cancel the repulsive ones and the coils also experience expansion in the radial direction.